# Seemingly missing Apple ID account

Tags: ipod-touch, apple-id, password, accounts

I have been buying apps for months using the exact same Apple ID password with no problem. Then my iPod Touch started telling me that it is wrong. I tried the "I forgot" option, but it did not help. I cannot access my account either and when I looked for it, the page said my account could not be found.

How do I get my account back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the steps on http://appleid.apple.com ? (+ answering the secure questions) (eg: Reset password)

Comment: As this is the way to manage your apple-id (and restore passwords in case you lost them), please approve my answer